# ASP .NET framework option not showing after downloaded Mono on Visual Studio 2019 for Mac

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mono, visual-studio-mac

I've been on this for 3 days already and I have no idea why it doesn't work like everyone else's. I have a Visual Studio 2019 for Mac installed, and since I would like to use ASP .NET Frameworks (Web Forms), I downloaded Mono.

I have checked the .NET runtime to set to Mono, and restarted the IDE. But when I want to create a new project and clicked on the Other section, there is no ASP .NET framework option. In tutorials and SO posts, I've seen that a lot of them managed to get the option to appear.

(To note: I'm only just starting to learn .NET framework since the company I want to apply for needs knowledge in ASP .NET Web Forms. I'm also on macOS Big Sur 11.4)

My **question** is, how do I get the option to appear like in the picture?

[I want it to have this option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDjGA.png)

[But it appears like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaJ8p.png)

I tried searching other references online to find the solution but I couldn't so I decided to ask here. I'd appreciate if anyone could show me how.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET project templates were removed from Visual Studio for Mac 8.9 and later versions since they are not supported.

If possible you should use ASP.NET Core instead.

Otherwise you are left with downloading the older [Visual Studio for Mac 8.8](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/65083286-ba60-4d43-a5bc-d8243c1823ea/23dd643bb6719d8f791601e4a97c2fdd/visualstudioformac-8.8.10.2.dmg) which still contains the ASP.NET project templates.

Comment: Dear Matt, thank you for the clarification! I downloaded the Visual Studio for Mac 8.8 and the option appeared!! Thank you so much for your help!!!!!!